# Force through potential energy: does the absolute value of energy has sense?

Tags: forces, potential, potential-energy, vector-fields

Force can be found from potential energy:

$$\vec{F}=-\nabla U$$

In other words, force depends on how the potential energy changes in space, but **not on the potential energy value**?

Or if we take some **constant** distance between two points, in case of a stronger field, will there be a higher potential difference than in the case of a weaker field? I think the potential difference for the same distance shouldn’t depend on field strength, or should it?

Is this incorrect? In this case, the absolute value **plays a role**. In the first case the difference is $2 \:\rm MJ$ in second $- 2 \:\rm mJ$.

[image]

Comment: I edited your question to make it clearer. Please feel free to rollback the edit if you find the edit isn't appropriate.

Comment: @FakeMod, no, appreciate

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the potential energy of a conservative system is mathematically undefined up to an additive constant, which means that we can pick a point in space to be our 'zero' potential energy and calculate differences from that. However generally we choose a convenient point in space so that the mathematical value of the potential energy has some physical meaning. For example with electrostatic force fields, we typically set zero to be 'at infinity' so that *U* represents the energy we can get from a system by completely separating all the charges. But the equations of motion would be the same if we chose a different point in space to be our 'zero' energy point., which would correspond to adding an overall constant.

For your second point, potential difference between two points does indeed increase for a stronger field. You should really think of potential energy as being a different and simpler representation of a (conservative) force field. So if you have a different force field, you will get a different potential energy field. In particular, a stronger force-field will lead to greater changes in the potential energy over the same distance - as is evident from your definition.

For your final point, you are comparing two fields where the absolute values have changed. But you have *not* added a constant to get from one field to the next, rather, you have *multiplied* the first field by $10^9$ to get the second. This has the effect of changing *differences* by a factor of $10^9$ and accordingly the forces themselves will be everywhere $10^9$ times stronger. This again is evident from your definition.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **Absolute potential energy is undefined**.

**Definition**: The change in potential energy of the system is defined as the negative of work done by the internal conservative forces of the system.

Potential energy difference definitely depends upon field strength. For ex: The gravitational potential energy difference due to field of a 1kg mass between two points  is definitely less than that due to earth's gravitational field.